# Is it safe to keep secrets in .env file in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I use docker compose to launch an app that uses `.env` files in each of its services.

When I add the `env_file` field in my docker compose file and launch it, all the env variables in the file are readable from the Docker Desktop app which I do not know if is secure, and I'm not sure if I like it since some of this variables are secrets to authenticate and authorize requests tokens.

Is it safe to keep it this way? Should I just remove the `env_file` field in my docker compose file? And if I do, will docker compose still recognise the env variables called in the code?

Comment: If you can't trust Docker Desktop, then you should not use it to launch containers that make use of secrets, even when using [Docker Secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/secret/). See [Docker Security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/)

Comment: It's not quite spelled out so succinctly in @code_monk's links: anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can pretty easily root the entire host, with Docker Desktop only providing some mitigation.  If you can see environment variable values through `docker inspect` or the Docker Desktop GUI then you can do a lot more damage with that level of privilege.  If only the root user can `docker` anything, then you're only exposing these credentials to already-trusted users.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, I guess anyone that gets access to my docker development environment would be a trusted user. Thank you! @DavidMaze